# Concentration inequality for the median

Tags: probability, inequality

Most concentration inequalities talk about deviation of the sample mean from the population mean. Is there a result bounding the probability of deviation of the sample median from the median of the density function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that your sample has $k$ elements, that $M$ is your median, and that in your distribution a single element exceeds $M+t$ with probability $p_t$ (dependent on $t$).

Then the probability that your median is at least $M+t$ is the probability that $k$ independent Bernoulli trials, each with success probability $p_t$, have among them at least $(k+1)/2$ successes (if $k$ is odd.  If $k$ is even you can replace $(k+1)/2$ by $k/2$ to get an upper bound on the probability).  You can then use concentration inequalities for the Binomial distribution (e.g. the Chernoff bound) to bound the probability this occurs in terms of $p_t$.

Comment: Is there any tighter approximation than this?

Answer (score 10):

The most convinient way to get concentration results on the median is [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality). Basically it states that among all geometrical shapes with equal area, the circle has the smallest perimeter. But when this result is generalized to a high-dimension metric space with a probability measure, you may get some counter-intuitive results called "measure concentration".

The most famous isoperimetric inequality maybe the [Talagrand's concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talagrand%27s_concentration_inequality). The inequality states that if $\Omega=\Omega_1\times\ldots\times\Omega_n$ is a product space endowed with a product probability measure and $A$ is a subset in this space, then for any $t>0$, there is
$$
    \Pr[A_t] \cdot \Pr\left[\overline{A_t}\right] \le e^{-t^2/4} \, , 
$$
where $A_t = \{ x \in \Omega : \rho(A, x) \le t \}$ with Talagrand's convex distance $\rho(\cdot, \cdot)$. You may refer to the wikipedia page to get the rigorous definition of those symbols in the inequality above.

From the inequality above, we can get a important conclusion: most probability mass (the measure!) is concentrated on events with probability at least $1/2$. For a intuitive explanation, consider $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ where $X_i$'s are **independent** random variables.And let $A=\{X\,|\,f(X)\leq M[f]\}$, where $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, and $M[f]$ represents the **median** of $f$. Then from Talagrand's inequality we can get the following results:
$$
\Pr[A]\cdot\Pr[X|f(X)>M[f]+t]\leq e^{-t^2/(4n)}\, .
$$
Then from the definition of median we know $\Pr[A]\geq 1/2$, so finally we have
$$
\Pr[X|f(X)>M[f]+t]\leq 2e^{-t^2/(4n)}\, ,
$$
a concentration on the median result. I have omitted many details in the proof and you may refer to [McDiarmid's nice survey](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/people/academic_staff/colin_mcdiarmid/?a=4139) for a detailed proof.