# Sharp Concentration of General Order Statistics of Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, order-statistics, concentration-of-measure

Suppose $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\overset{i.i.d.}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Consider the order statistics $X_{(1)} \geq X_{(2)} \geq \ldots \geq X_{(n)}$. Then the Gaussian maxima $X_{(1)}$ has sub-gaussian type concentration: [Tail bounds for maximum of sub-Gaussian random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676407/tail-bounds-for-maximum-of-sub-gaussian-random-variables). The median $X_{(\lceil n/2 \rceil)}$ also has sub-gaussian type concentration: [Concentration inequality for the median](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517929/concentration-inequality-for-the-median). But the dominating concentration result for general order statistics $X_{(k)}$, $k\neq 1$ or $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ only gives sub-exponential type of tail bound (Berinstein-like inequalities), c.f.:

*Boucheron, Stéphane Vincent; Thomas, Maud*, [**Concentration inequalities for order statistics**](https://doi.org/10.1214/ECP.v17-2210), Electron. Commun. Probab. 17, Paper No. 51, 12 p. (2012). [ZBL1349.60021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1349.60021).

I am wondering is the Bernstein-like inequaility the sharpest concentration for general order statistics of Gaussian? Can $X_{(k)}$ also have sub-gaussian concentration for general $k$?